# Actuator 2.X without Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

Following some links I tried to setup actuator 2.X without Spring Boot, but no help.

Tried with `/health`, `/application/health`, `/actuator/health` but none worked. I earlier used Actuator 1.X and just by adding `EndpointWebMvcManagementContextConfiguration`, `EndpointAutoConfiguration`, `PublicMetricsAutoConfiguration` and `HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration` to my xml context and pom dependencies, it worked smoothly.

Now my requirement is to add/remove health indicators on the fly, so need to move on to Actuator 2.X.

Answer (score 1):

I've been fiddling recently with including Spring Actuator 2.x to an existing Spring MVC project. This is a configuration which worked

```
@Configuration
@Import({
        EndpointAutoConfiguration.class,
        HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.class,

        InfoEndpointAutoConfiguration.class,
        HealthEndpointAutoConfiguration.class,

        WebEndpointAutoConfiguration.class,
        ServletManagementContextAutoConfiguration.class,
        ManagementContextAutoConfiguration.class,
})
@EnableConfigurationProperties(CorsEndpointProperties.class)
class ActuatorConfiguration {

    @Bean //taken from WebMvcEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class
    public WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping webEndpointServletHandlerMapping(WebEndpointsSupplier webEndpointsSupplier,
                                                                         ServletEndpointsSupplier servletEndpointsSupplier, ControllerEndpointsSupplier controllerEndpointsSupplier,
                                                                         EndpointMediaTypes endpointMediaTypes, CorsEndpointProperties corsProperties,
                                                                         WebEndpointProperties webEndpointProperties) {
        List<ExposableEndpoint<?>> allEndpoints = new ArrayList<>();
        Collection<ExposableWebEndpoint> webEndpoints = webEndpointsSupplier.getEndpoints();
        allEndpoints.addAll(webEndpoints);
        allEndpoints.addAll(servletEndpointsSupplier.getEndpoints());
        allEndpoints.addAll(controllerEndpointsSupplier.getEndpoints());
        EndpointMapping endpointMapping = new EndpointMapping(webEndpointProperties.getBasePath());
        return new WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping(endpointMapping, webEndpoints, endpointMediaTypes,
                corsProperties.toCorsConfiguration(),
                new EndpointLinksResolver(allEndpoints, webEndpointProperties.getBasePath()));
    }

    @Bean
    DispatcherServletPath dispatcherServletPath() {
        return () -> "/";
    }

}
```

I did include

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.18.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

for compatibility with the baseline Spring version I've been using (5.1.19.RELEASE)

The actuator endpoints are exposed with `/actuator/*`

Answer (score -2):

In spring Boot 2.x, the endpoints has been changed . You can refer this 
[Exposing Endpoints](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-endpoints-enabling-endpoints)
The detailed migration guide is here [detailed migration guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide#endpoints)

To change which endpoints are exposed, use the following technology-specific include and exclude properties:

**application.properties**

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

**Output**

```
      {"_links":{"self":{"href":"http://localhost:8080/actuator","templated":false},"auditevents":{"href":"http://localhost:8080/actuator/auditevents","templated":false},"beans":{"href":"http://localhost:8080/actuator/beans","templated":false},"caches-cache":{"href":"http://localhost:8080/actuator/caches/{cache}","templated":true},"caches":{"href":"http://localhost:8080/actuator/caches","templated":false},
..................
...........
...................
}}}
```